# Why is firebug telling me my JavaScript array is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Just started working on a basic grid analysis algorithm in JavaScript but I have come up against an error that is perplexing me.

```
var max = 9;
var testArray = new Array(
  ['7', '3', '9', '6', '4', '1', '5', '2', '8'],
  ['1', '8', '2', '7', '5', '3', '4', '6', '9'],
  ['9', '5', '7', '3', '8', '2', '1', '4', '6'],
  ['3', '1', '4', '9', '6', '7', '2', '8', '5'],
  ['6', '2', '8', '5', '1', '4', '9', '3', '7'],
  ['5', '4', '6', '2', '9', '8', '3', '7', '1'],
  ['8', '7', '1', '4', '3', '5', '6', '9', '2'],
  ['2', '9', '3', '1', '7', '6', '8', '5', '4']
);

function checkYoSelf(myGrid) {
  var i; var j;
  var horizLine = new String;
  for( i = 0; i <= (max - 1); i++ ) {
    for( j = 0; j <= (max - 1); j++) {
      document.write(i+"<br />");
      horizLine += myGrid[i][j];
    }
    var test = RegExp(i, "ig");
    var result = new Array(horizLine.match(test));
    if( result.length > 1 ) {
      alert("fail");
    }    
  }
}

html file has <a href='#' onclick="checkYoSelf(testArray);">check</a>
```

According to firebug `myGrid[i]` is undefined but I'm not sure why this should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would like to propose to you i < max as opposed to i <= (max - 1).

Comment: Also, just use var horizLine = "". No need for new String. Same with arrays. arr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];

Comment: To concatenate array elements into a string, just use Array.join('').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is working for me... I've just replaced your "max" variable to something more dynamic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testArray = new Array(
        ['7', '3', '9', '6', '4', '1', '5', '2', '8'],
        ['1', '8', '2', '7', '5', '3', '4', '6', '9'],
        ['9', '5', '7', '3', '8', '2', '1', '4', '6'],
        ['3', '1', '4', '9', '6', '7', '2', '8', '5'],
        ['6', '2', '8', '5', '1', '4', '9', '3', '7'],
        ['5', '4', '6', '2', '9', '8', '3', '7', '1'],
        ['8', '7', '1', '4', '3', '5', '6', '9', '2'],
        ['2', '9', '3', '1', '7', '6', '8', '5', '4']
    );

    function checkYoSelf(myGrid) {
        var i;
        var j;
        var horizLine = new String;

        var maxRows = myGrid.length;
        for( i = 0; i < maxRows; i++ ) {
            var maxColumns = myGrid[i].length;
            for( j = 0; j < maxColumns; j++) {
                document.write(i+"<br />");
                horizLine += myGrid[i][j];
            }

            var test = RegExp(i, "ig");
            var result = new Array(horizLine.match(test));
            if( result.length > 1 ) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<a href='#' onclick="checkYoSelf(testArray);">check</a>
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with this, but at least it doesn't give any error.

Comment: interesting, your version doesn't throw any errors however when I separate the javascript into a separate js file and source in the html head the same error that I mentioned earlier occurs. Clearly I need to work a lot harder at my javascript!

Answer (score 1):

where is `max` coming from?

> max is defined globally (in this case max = 9)

you only have 8 rows.

Comment: max is defined globally (in this case max = 9)

Comment: @Nick: There are only 8 outer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to nickf's answer: it's because max is 9, but you only have 8 rows in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug says

> max is not defined

You're trying to access testArray[8] inside checkYoSelf(testArray) when  the last index is testArray[7].

Answer (score 0):

`testArray` contains 8 elements.  You're accessing `testArray[8]`, which is invalid because the index must be 0..7 (0..8-1).  Add another row to your array, or rewrite the first for as:

```
for( i = 0; i <= (max - 2); i++ ) {
```

Comment: max - 2? why not just set max to be the actual max?

Comment: @nickf, I don't know.  I'm working off the code I'm given.  If you set the actual max (the variable), you'll be changing other parts of the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite

```
for( i = 0; i <= (max - 1); i++ ) {
   for( j = 0; j <= (max - 1); j++) {
```

as

```
for( i = 0; i < (max - 1); i++ ) {
   for( j = 0; j < max; j++) {
```

it should work. The first dimension of your grid is only 8.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone for their help, the firebug error is no longer occuring now that the code is:

```
var testArray = new Array(
  ['7', '3', '9', '6', '4', '1', '5', '2', '8'],
  ['1', '8', '2', '7', '5', '3', '4', '6', '9'],
  ['9', '5', '7', '3', '8', '2', '1', '4', '6'],
  ['3', '1', '4', '9', '6', '7', '2', '8', '5'],
  ['5', '4', '6', '2', '9', '8', '3', '7', '1'],
  ['6', '2', '8', '5', '1', '4', '9', '3', '7'],
  ['8', '7', '1', '4', '3', '5', '6', '9', '2'],
  ['2', '9', '3', '1', '7', '6', '8', '5', '4'],
  ['2', '9', '3', '1', '7', '6', '8', '5', '4']
);

function checkYoSelf(myGrid) {
  var i;
  var j;
  var horizLine = new String;
  var max = myGrid.length;

  for( i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      horizLine += myGrid[i][j];
    }
    var test = RegExp(i, "ig");
    var result = new Array(horizLine.match(test));
    if( result.length > 1 ) {
      alert("fail");
    }    
  }
}
```